# UNC path syntax when remote system drive is not C:\

Tags: windows, powershell

I have the following PowerShell code:

```
$Domain = "VM-PRO"

[string] $SystemDrive = Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -CimSession $CimServer |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty SystemDrive

$SystemDrive = $SystemDrive.TrimEnd(":")

$AppPath = "\\$Domain\$SystemDrive`$\Users\$User\AppData"
Test-Path $AppPath
```

Which works just fine, System drive on remote server is `C:\` and `AppPath` expands to:

```
\\VM-PRO\C$\Users\User\AppData
```

My question is, what if system drive on remote computer is `X:\` or something else?
Wouldn't that result is non existent share? ex:

```
\\VM-PRO\X$\Users\User\AppData
```

What I'm asking, is default share `C$` always `C$` or does it depend on actual system drive letter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does depend on the actual drive letter.

By default, Windows creates the following admin shares:

- Admin$ — Remote admin (this is the %SystemRoot% directory)
- IPC$ — Remote IPC (used in named pipes)
- C$ — Default Drive Share

If there are other partitions on the computer that are assigned a
drive letter, they are also automatically published as admin shares
(D$, E$, etc.).

If you are using a shared printer, there should be
Print$; and FAX$ for a fax server.

Comment: That's what I was believeing but needed someone to autoratively confirm.